# Eclipse not running on Opensuse 12.3

Tags: linux, android, eclipse, opensuse

I have just downloaded the Android SDK for Linux. I am running OpenSuse 12.3. When I try to run Eclipse, there is an error that says that there is no program to run executable files. So, I use the following ways to make the Eclipse program executable.

1. Right click on the program and open the 'Properties' option to check the 'Allow executing file as program' checkbox. But as soon as I check the box, it gets unchecked and I am not able to run Eclipse.
2. I tried using the chmod +x command but there was no change.

How do I  make Eclipse executable?

Comment: you have a linux version of eclipse, right? how about a java JDK?

Comment: yes. i have the linux version of eclipse which i downloaded from the android website. and i have the openjdk installed.